# get zero instead of a float value-Objective C

Tags: ios, expression

I have an expression from the strCal string strcal value is @"((24 - 18) / 87) * 100"
I want to have the result correct to 4 decimal so I retrieve the result using floatValue method

But instead of 6.8966 I get 0

This is my code

```
NSString *strCal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"   
                      ((%d%@)%@)%@",number,strMinus,strDivide,strMultiple];
    NSExpression *exp=[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:strCal];
    float result=[[exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"result:%f",result);
```

result:0.000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself by converting the 87 in the string strCal to float value like below

@"((24 - 18) / 87.00) * 100"

why because means the either the dividend or divisor has to be in float so that the compiler(LLVM) output the answer in float

Comment: As you said, dividend or divisor has to be a float. In fact, in depends of the compilator. Sometimes only the dividend has to be at least a float, or only the dividor, and sometimes, both... SO to be careful, I recommand to convert both of them into float.

Comment: I did not try with XCode and the versions of the compiler. I know that from colleagues who works on others projects in C (for electronics) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to User [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) Which is best in this situation. I have used it in One of my project which is facing same problem as you have faced

`DDMathEvaluator *eval = [DDMathEvaluator defaultMathEvaluator];
   id value=[eval evaluateString:@"1/2" withSubstitutions:nil error:&error];
   NSLog(@"Result %@",value);
   Result 0.5`